# PHPExcel Render html tags in mysql table row

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, phpexcel

I am using **`phpExcel`** library.I have an export script working fine which fetch all data from a MySQL table.Now the MySQL table has a row called `product_info` which contains HTML tags and styles.

Now how can I render those styles for that just one row, which contain HTML elements like `<font color="Red">Hello</font>`. This HTML tags varies. So how can I render them?

Please advise

Answer (score 2):

You can't. You could parse the HTML markup and use it to build a rich text object, that you could then set as the content of a cell; but there is no conversion from HTML to rich text built into PHPExcel itself, so you'd need to do that by hand.

Comment: Ack, noticed your answer in 2010 about this: http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/230732 - is it still that low on the priority list? Boohoo now I have to actually work :)

Comment: @aditya - It's still low on the priority list... noone has yet provided a patch to do this, and I've not had time to write one... I've only just got UTF-8 working in Rich Text objects for the Excel5 Writer